# How does the structure of a Luk-Vuillemin multiplier differ from a Wallace or Dadda multiplier?

Tags: arithmetic, digital-circuits, multiplication

I've read that Luk-Vuillemin multipliers are similar to Wallace multipliers but partition their inputs in a different way. How exactly does this partitioning work, how does it change the structure of the multiplier, and why does it give it a more regular structure which is preferred for fabrication?